# How can I get a command executed in Capistrano 3 into a variable?

Tags: ruby, capistrano, capistrano3

I'm trying to run execute on a command like below in my deploy.rb:

`results = execute 'somecommand'`

It does not seem that `execute` returns the results of the command. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use the `capture` command.

```
result = capture(:echo, "hello world")
result # => "hello world"
```

An example is also shown on the home page of the Capistrano docs: http://capistranorb.com